# How to make code assist work in eclipse using jakarta faces + facelets

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to use eclipse's code assist to access my ManagedBean, on pages with Facelets, but when I press Ctrl+Space, it doesn't work. Nothing appears.

How can I enable this feature in Eclipse? Is this a known issue?

I tried installing JBoss Tools 4.26 and it didn't work.

Is there any configuration for this to work in the latest version of eclipse?

information:

- I'm using a fresh installation of eclipse 2022-12.
- openjdk 17,
- Tomcat 10.1
- Jakarta 10,
- Jakarta Servlet 6,
- Jakarta CDI 4,
- Jakarta Faces 4

Comment: Have a look at https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2020/04/jsf-23-tutorial-with-eclipse-maven.html

Comment: hi, I saw this link, it is very good and shows all the steps on how to configure the environment, but it doesn't help with my problem. with the environment configured how to make eclipe's code assist identify classes annotated as @Named in *.xhtml pages

Comment: Open the facelet with "JBoss Tools HTML editor"

Comment: @grigouille unfortunately it didn't work in eclipse 2022-12 + jakarta 10